# Getting 'Uncaught Error: Script error' for a declared dependency when using r.js

Tags: requirejs, r.js

I couldn't find an answer for my issue on SO or Github, so I am posting this:

I created a repo for this issue: 
https://github.com/saviomuc/requireJSMultiPage

I tried to set up require.js for a multipage project.

All is fine when I am running the page.
But when I try to optimize the files with r.js I am getting this error:

```
GET http://localhost:63342/requirejs/www-build/js/library.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:7
Uncaught Error: Script error for: library
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

The setup is like this:

```
js/app/app1.js
js/app/app1jq.js
js/lib/require.js
js/lib/library.js
main-page1.js
```

Currently require.js loads a file (main-page1.js) which contains this code

```
require(['common','app/app1','app/app1jq'], function (config) {});
```

`common.js` contains

```
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            library: 'lib/library'
        }
    });
    console.log('This is the config!');
```

`app1jq.js` contains

```
    define(function (require) {
        var library = require('library');
        console.log('This is dependent on library');
    });
```

Could this be an issue with the optimizer? Or did I do something wrong?

Best and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `common` is not guaranteed to be loaded first. So when RequireJS gets to `require('library')` then the configuration may or may not have been set. When you call `require(['a', 'b', 'c'], function () {})` RequireJS is free to load `c` first, or `b` first, or `a` first. The order is not set. The only guarantee is that all the modules will be loaded before the callback is called.

So change `main-page1.js` so that it contains:

```
require(['common'], function () {
    require(['app/app1','app/app1jq']);
});
```

This will ensure that `common` is loaded before any of the code that depends on your configuration.

Comment: Thanks. That lead me into the right direction.
I created a new file app/page1 and referenced it from the main-page1.js

`    require(['common'], function () {
        require(['app/page1']);
    });
`
This file contains:
`
    define(function (require) {
        var app1 = require('./app1'),
            app1jq = require('./app1jq');

        console.log('This is the page 1');
    });
`
And it works =) Did I miss something else?