# How to solve Script error for: node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, mailjet

I try to use the Mailjet Wrapper for Node.js for my Ionic app.

Now I try to connect to the Mail by using following code :-

```
var connection = require(['node-mailjet'], function(mailjet){
   mailjet.connect('api key', 'api secret'); 
});
```

But I'm getting this error:-

> require.min.js:8 Uncaught Error: Script error for: node-mailjet

Does anybody know how to solve it? I already installed the `require.js` library.

Comment: Can [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974248/getting-uncaught-error-script-error-for-a-declared-dependency-when-using-r-js) help you?

Comment: the issue in the link is caused by unsolved dependencies between the required modules...I just have one so I unfortunately that doesn't help :(

Comment: Check the link in the updated answer below.

Comment: I haven't heard of anyone including npm packages in their ionic apps that weren't specifically designed for the front end, have you done this before or have some lead you're following?

Comment: No, but why shouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the link](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded) for the error you specified in the comment of this answer. Here you can find your solution

> This occurs when there is a require('name') call, but the 'name' module has not been loaded yet.

May be something like the above statement is happening in your case i.e. `node-mailjet` is not loaded when you are trying to use it. (as per the error in the comment I have searched).

Comment: I tried that first but it caused a 'Module name "node-mailjet" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])' error